# Logical error in Palindrome program

Tags: c

**Problem-**
To reverse digits of three digit no. and check whether they are palindrome or not. 
**Logical error:** Following code always displaying for all inputs "not a palindrome number."

```
   d=0;
   scanf("%d",&n);
   a=n; 

   for(i=1;i<=3;i++)    //loop will run 3 times corresponding to number of digits 
       {
       c=a%10;
       a=a/10;

       for(f=100;f>=1;f=f/10)   //for arranging digits in reverse order in number
           {
           d=d+f*c;
           } 

       }
   if(d==n)                       //checking whether number is palindrome or not  
   printf("palindrome");
   else printf("not a palindrome");
```

Comment: You're looping through hundreds, tens, and ones and adding each digit to all three. So if your three-digit number is xyz, you're getting xxx+yyy+zzz in d.

Comment: inner for-loop wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d=0;
f=100;
scanf("%3d", &n);
a=n; 

for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
    c=a%10;
    a=a/10;

    d=d+f*c;
    f=f/10;// f/=10;
}
if(d==n)
    printf("palindrome");
else
    printf("not a palindrome");
```

Answer (score 0):

initialize `f=100` before your first `for` loop will work.